# New Project Error Module with id ':::app' not found

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

**The exception log is as follows:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Module with id ':::app' not found
- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

- Exception is:
  com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Module with id ':::app' not found
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:439)
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:139)
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:43)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:104)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:84)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:57)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:81)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:98)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:95)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:73)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:58)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
  at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:50)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:38)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
  at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)

**I have found the cause of the exception**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
}
```

**Adjust to**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.4" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
}
```

This will work normally, but I would like to know how to run it using 8.2.0

Thanks.

Comment: App module is available in your project.

Comment: @KishanViramgama If adjust to 8.1.4, it is available